# AWS Security Hub BatchImportFindings API: AccessDeniedException even if the user has proper policies and roles

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to ingest security findings into the AWS security hub via an external Python script. For that, I'm using this API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/1.0/APIReference/API_BatchImportFindings.html

I've written a simple python script to perform the batch import findings into AWS security hub as follows:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('securityhub', 
                        region_name='us-east-2',
                        aws_access_key_id='API_KEY',
                        aws_secret_access_key='API_SECRET')
response = client.batch_import_findings(finding_obj)
```

But this is throwing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_hub.py", line 504, in <module>
    'Status': 'NEW',
  File "C:\Users\Aspire5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aspire5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the BatchImportFindings operation: User: arn:aws:iam::355025806062:user/Kaushal is not authorized to perform: securityhub:BatchImportFindings
```

I've created a user on AWS and that has the following permission policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "securityhub:BatchImportFindings"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried to simulate the same policy with the simulator provided by AWS and according to that, my user has access to this operation but it's failing via API call. Here is the screenshot of the simulator:

[image: s]

Answer (score 5):

Kaushal28,

Your finding_obj is probably having a wrong ProductARN

ProductARN should be set like this:

```
productArn = "arn:aws:securityhub:"+ AWS_REGION +":" + ACCOUNT_ID +":product/" + ACCOUNT_ID +"/default"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 mistakes which might cause this error :

1. Running the API call in **wrong region**
2. Not having **permission** to run the API
3. Specifying wrong **Product ARN**

### 1. Wrong Region

The region you mention in boto3 client should be **same as the region where you have Security Hub enabled**.

(Boto3 version used = 1.17.38)

```
import boto3

security_hub_client = boto3.client('securityhub',
                        aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
                        aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY,
                        region_name = REGION)
```

[Github Issue](https://github.com/toniblyx/prowler/issues/618)

### 2. No permission

The user corresponding to the Access Key and Secret Key you used to create the boto3 client should have the **securityhub:*** permission.

Having only the **securityhub:BatchImportFindings** permission for all resources should also work fine if **BatchImportFindings is the only API** you will be using, meaning that you do not need the other Security Hub APIs.

Permission screenshot -
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJrE6.png)

Permission json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "securityhub:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

### 3. Product ARN

Specify the **Security Hub Default** product ARN properly.

Format :

**arn:aws:securityhub:*<REGION>*:*<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>*:product/*<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>*/default**

```
Findings=[
        {
            'SchemaVersion': '2018-10-08',
            'Id': 'testfinding1',
            'ProductArn': 'arn:aws:securityhub:' + REGION + ':' + AWS_ACCOUNT_ID + ':product/' + AWS_ACCOUNT_ID + '/default',
            'Types': [
                'Test'
            ],
            'GeneratorId': 'generator1',
            'AwsAccountId': AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
            'CreatedAt': '2021-10-29T14:40:13.933Z',
            'UpdatedAt': '2021-10-29T14:40:13.933Z',
            'Severity': {
                'Label': 'MEDIUM',
            },
            'Title': 'Test Finding 1',
            'Description': 'Test Finding 1',
            'Resources': [
                {
                    'Type': 'Other',
                    'Id': 'xxx'                
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

[Above answer by Tarik Makota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62703928/8504709)

### Run the API

```
security_hub_client.batch_import_findings(Findings=Findings)
```

### References

- Steps : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-custom-providers.html
- API reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/1.0/APIReference/API_BatchImportFindings.html
- Python API reference : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.17.83/reference/services/securityhub.html#SecurityHub.Client.batch_import_findings